# Replace DataSource bean with H2 DataSource at runtime

Tags: testing, junit, h2, spring-test

I'm working on a test framework.

I want to replace a MySQL `DataSource` bean with one for H2 (that isn't configured as a bean in XML) when some use cases require H2.

Some use cases still use MySQL, so I can't modify the `DataSource` bean config directly. Only one `DataSource` should be configured in the Spring XML configuration file (no H2 `DataSource` configured).

Is there any way to replace the `DataSource` bean in the `sqlmapclient` (ibatis) at runtime?

Comment: Have you considered simply configuring Spring's support for _bean definition profiles_ and using `@ActiveProfiles` in your test classes?

Comment: hI @SamBrannen, that is well, but every project should do some change to add profiles config. I hope others use my test framework with zero change. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Spring's support for *bean definition profiles* and `@ActiveProfiles` in your test classes.

However, if you are not willing or able to do that, another option would be to implement a custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that *replaces* the bean definition for the MySQL `DataSource` with a bean definition for the H2 `DataSource`. Keep in mind that, if you go that route, you will still need conditional logic (in your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`) to decide whether or not to replace the MySQL `DataSource` bean definition.

Comment: i can use BeanFactoryPostProcessor to  replace datasource in the junit. So projects need not do anything. Thanks very much.:D